# Log rotation of diag logs?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

In on of our Oracle 11.2.0 installations the directory `database\diag\rdbms\$DB\$DB\alert` is filled with hundreds of xml files (`log.xml`, `log1.xml` ...). Can Oracle be configured to do log rotation there? And where are these files used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle won't do this natively. You'll have to use an external utility to do this.

On Unix systems this is usually achieved with logrotate.